# Set skin url as unsecure in email template at the backend

Tags: url, email-templates, html, https, skin

Is there a way to set skin url to be unsecure in **img** tag in email template content at the Magento backend.

My tag would be:

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/registration-email/logo.jpg" _area="frontend" _package="xyz"}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

### Background

This is one of those instances where PHP loose-typing was not handled carefully. If you look at the implementation of `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getSkinUrl`, which is what the `{{skin url...}}` CMS directive invokes, you will see that it makes use of a method named `getSkinBaseUrl` that builds the URL. That method determines whether to make it secure like this:

```
isset($params['_secure'])? (bool)$params['_secure'] : null
```

When you cast a string to a boolean in PHP, [certain rules apply to how it will be converted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). These are values that will be converted to `FALSE`:

> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE.

Since `(bool)"false" === TRUE`, and they make that clear in the examples in the linked documentation, it’s only a happy accident that the XML param `_secure="true"` causes URLs to use https. Normally this is fine because we typically use this param to force a URL to be secure, but in this case we are doing the opposite. You could put nearly any string value in that param and it would create a secure URL, which leads me to...

### Solution

This will allow you to force a URL in a CMS directive to be unsecure:

```
{{skin url="..." _secure="0"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `_secure="false"` and then try. ie

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/registration-email/logo.jpg" _area="frontend" _package="xyz" _secure="false"}}" />
```

Don't forget to clear cache after the changes made.

Comment: Ya i tried this but it isnt working.